# Populate different gridview by clicking different button

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my web page header, there are several buttons. What I want is to click each button to display a desired table in a gridview.

**click button1** 
    Display table in gridview 1.

**click button2** Display table in gridview 2, Gridview 1 disappeared.

The header and buttons are persisting in the page. I don't want to redirect the current page to different pages. I only want to implement the function in one web page.

Comment: Are you sharing the datasource between both gridviews? can you post your code that you have tried?

Comment: No. I tried to use MultiView, but I could not place gridview inside MultiView control.

Comment: What about the four answers below?

Comment: Answer is good. Do we need to set other datasource are null?

Comment: It would more efficient if you are concerned with/or are using the ViewState as Kelsey mentioned. You should try it with it and without and see how it suits your application.

Comment: If there are 10 buttons, it becomes more complicated. I hope just use one gridview by slecting different command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ASPX**

```
  <div>
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
         </asp:GridView>
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
         </asp:GridView>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
         <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click" />
     </div>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    GridView2.Visible = !GridView1.Visible;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Visible = false;
    GridView2.Visible = !GridView1.Visible;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

You may need to pass in the .DataBind() call depending on how you are binding your data to the gridviews.

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
buttin1_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ gridview1.visible = true; gridview1.DataBind(); gridview2.visible = false;}

buttin2_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ gridview2.visible = true; gridview2.DataBind(); gridview1.visible = false;}
```

or

```
 buttin1_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ gridview1.DataBind(); gridview2.Rows.Clear();}

buttin2_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ gridview2.DataBind(); gridview1.Rows.Clear();}
```

Answer (score 0):

On each button click just bind your `GridView` as needed.  For example:

Button1 clicked do:

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    grdYourGrid1.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    grdYourGrid1.DataBind();
    grdYourGrid1.Visible = true;

    grdYourGrid2.DataSource = null;
    grdYourGrid2.DataBind();
    grdYourGrid2.Visible = false;
}
```

Then do the opposite for Button2.  I suggest rebinding and nulling the non visible grid so the `ViewState` doesn't get bloated when not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the Page_Load

```
button1.Click+=(s,ev)=>
    {
        gridview1.visible = true; 
        gridview1.DataBind();
    };
button2.Click+=(s,ev)=>
    {
        gridview2.DataBind(); 
        gridview1.visible = false;
    };
```